# method reference in java 8?

Tags: java, methods, lambda, reference, functional-interface

I have read in tutorials that while using method reference the arguments must be matched in Functional interface's method and method that we are referring to.
So iam getting following error.

```
public class MethodRefTest 
{
    public static void m1(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("Hey in method 1");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Runnable r=MethodRefTest::m1; //Compile time error

    }
}
```

Now that i have understood that why iam getting that error
Look at the below code snippet

```
package com;

public class Transaction {

    private int id;
    private int value;

    public Transaction(int id,int value)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}


package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MethodRefTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Transaction t1=new Transaction(1,20);
        Transaction t2=new Transaction(2,30);
        List<Transaction> list=new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        list.add(t1);
        list.add(t2);
        List<Integer> intList=list.stream().map(Transaction::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(intList);

    }
}
```

In the map method that i have used, it accepts Function FunctionalInterface ...but the method reference that i have used doesnt have any arguments, but the apply(T t) method of Function has one argument, and getId() doesnt have any argument ,In this case it is not throwing any error even though arguments are not matched.

Please help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 0):

> but the apply(T t) method of Function has one argument, and getId()
>   doesnt have any argument

The `apply` function takes in an argument as one type of data and returns another type of data. In your case, its as if:

```
public Integer apply(Transaction transaction) {
    return transaction.getId();
}
```

The complete `Function` within the `map` operation of course defines the input and the output type for the transformation as :

```
new Function<Transaction, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Transaction transaction) {
        return transaction.getId();
    }
}
```

---

On the contrary, in your code `m1` needs an argument of integer type to be supplied to it, which would result in a `void` output. Hence, your implementation matches being a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) and can be represented as :

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer = MethodRefTest::m1
```

Comment: To really create a `Runnable` provide it an input as `Runnable r = () -> m1(2); // replacing 2 with any integer value`

Answer (score 0):

The *method reference*

```
Transaction::getId
```

equals to the *lambda expression*

```
(Transaction t) -> t.getId()
```

Which you can see accept a `Transaction` argument and returns an `int` value

It's a perfectly valid `Function<Transaction, Integer>` signature, as it does fullfil its requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler is allowed to match a method reference to a non-`static` method with *n - 1* arguments as if it matches, with the object itself as the first argument.  The relevant [section of the JLS is 15.13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> Otherwise, given a targeted function type with parameter types P<sub>1</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub> and a set of potentially applicable methods, the compile-time declaration is selected as follows:
>
> - If the method reference expression has the form *ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier*, then two searches for a most specific applicable method are performed. Each search is as specified in §15.12.2.2 through §15.12.2.5, with the clarifications below. Each search produces a set of applicable methods and, possibly, designates a most specific method of the set. In the case of an error as specified in §15.12.2.4, the set of applicable methods is empty. In the case of an error as specified in §15.12.2.5, there is no most specific method.
>
>   In the first search, the method reference is treated as if it were an invocation with argument expressions of types P<sub>1</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub>. Type arguments, if any, are given by the method reference expression.
>
>   In the second search, if P<sub>1</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub> is not empty and P<sub>1</sub> is a subtype of *ReferenceType*, then the method reference expression is treated as if it were a method invocation expression with argument expressions of types P<sub>2</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub>.
>
>   If the first search produces a most specific method that is `static`, and the set of applicable methods produced by the second search contains no non-`static` methods, then the compile-time declaration is the most specified method of the first search.
>
>   Otherwise, if the set of applicable methods produced by the first search contains no `static` methods, and the second search produces a most specific method that is non-`static`, then the compile-time declaration is the most specific method of the second search.

The "first search" is the direct match of method parameters to a functional interface type.  The "second search" adds some flexibility in that the object instance itself from a method reference may serve as the first parameter match to a functional interface.

In your top example, the `m1` method is `static` and there is no instance that can be implicitly the first argument, so the "second search" doesn't apply here.

In your bottom example, the `getId` is not static, and the "second search" above applies.  Here, `getId` has no arguments, so the set of parameters "P2-Pn" is empty.  However, the object itself is the implicit first argument, so it matches the functional signature `Function<Transaction, Integer>` expected by the `map` method in `Stream`.